# How to display the details about the selected option of drop down list in php

Tags: php

I have one project developed using codeigniter framework.

In that I have one drop down list of all the countries.

When the user selects one of the country from the dropdown I need to display the information about that particular country...

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you be more precise in your query? It is very vague!

Comment: self development this code

Comment: where you want to display information of country?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to do this way, irrespective of the framework you use:

1. Develop a Server Side PHP script, that responds with the information about the selected country, with the input of your country parameter.
2. When you trigger an `onChange` event in the `<select>` in your UI, fire an AJAX call fetching the Server Side PHP script's response and showing it in the `<div>` or some area in the UI.

If you are allowed to use jQuery, this can be made simple. Have an `ID` for your `<select>` tag:

```
<select id="countries">
    <!-- Options populated by php -->
</select>
```

When you do an `onChange` event, bind the below function:

```
$("#countries").change(function(){
    countryValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax("countries-info.php", {country: countryValue}, function(message){
        $("#countryInfo").html(message);
    });
});
```

Ultimately, you should have a structure similar to this in your HTML:

```
<select id="countries">
    <!-- Options populated by php -->
</select>
<div id="countryInfo"></div>
```

And in your `countries-info.php`, you should have something like this:

```
<?php
    $country = clean($_GET["country"]);
    // Connect to the DB
    databaseConnect($username, $password, $database);
    $results = $databaseObject->query("SELECT `info` FROM `countries` WHERE `country`='$country'");
    $countryInfo = $results["info"];
    die($countryInfo);
?>
```

The above is a pseudo code of what you need to do:

- `clean()` is used to clean the response from any SQL Injection. You can use something like `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, if you are using MySQL.
- `databaseConnect()` is used to connect to the database server and select the database.
- `$databaseObject` is the database connection object.
- `$databaseObject->query()` function executes the query on the database server and fetches one single row based on the country.

Hope this guides you in the right direction!

Comment: Without using javascript can I access the value of drop down list ?

Comment: @SwathiS You need to use JavaScript to get the contents of the DOM and manipulate it. If not, you need more server side processing, to take in the current state and stuff like that. Easy to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Why implementing new connection (As mentioned it was developed using CI, Connection can be obtained)  :P .. However, i appreciate the way PHP-MYSQLI Handled

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in JQuery for example, using [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

This will trigger everytime you change the country, you'll need to get the country name and then display needed information.

If you want to use vanilla JS, you can use [onChange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done solely with PHP, you will need JavaScript ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080098/dropdown-using-javascript-onchange)) and additionally AJAX if the " information about that particular country" comes from the back-end. Add a change listener to the drop down list and if it fires update the HTML accordingly.