# How to fire click event on select drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following code for drop down select showing drop down list using text and values.i google many codes as possible but none of them worked.what i wanted to show the selected drop down menu item in alert dialog.I already tried jquery and javascript codes but they are not working please help me to out of this problem

```
  <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="fleft " id="drop-down">

                    <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select"  >

                        <option value="1" >Home</option>
                        <option value="2" >Movies</option>

                        <option value="3" >T.V. Shows</option>
                        <option value="4" >Photos</option>
                        <option value="5" >Site Help</option>

                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: use on-change.. @dhiraj

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080098/dropdown-using-javascript-onchange refer this..

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Comment: i have aleready tried many solutions and given solutions to this question but non of them is working or something went wrong which i am not understanding @epascarello

Comment: Can you create a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/) with what you've tried so far so we can investigate further ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do so using jQuery like this

```
$(document).on('change',"#cd-dropdown", function(){
 alert($(this).val());  // will display selected option's value
 alert($(this).find('option:selected').text()); //will display selected option's text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you could do something like this:

```
$('#cd-dropdown').bind('change', function () {
   alert($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

If you want the value instead of the text, use `.val()`

Answer (score 0):

on changing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cd-dropdown").change(function(){
       alert($(this).find('option:selected').val()); // val or text
    });
});
```

or on loading

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     alert($("#cd-dropdown").find('option:selected').val()); // val or text
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Updated link](http://jsfiddle.net/6uyz4b8x/76/)

HTML code:

```
 <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="fleft " id="drop-down">

                        <select id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select"  onmousedown="this.value='';" onchange="jsFunction(this.value);" >

                            <option value="1" >Home</option>
                            <option value="2" >Movies</option>

                            <option value="3" >T.V. Shows</option>
                            <option value="4" >Photos</option>
                            <option value="5" >Site Help</option>

                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

JS code:

```
function jsFunction(value)
{
    alert(value);
}
```