# ClientID as parameter in javascript on dropdownlist box during selection change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

but I don't know why it doesn't work on my project. I just want to call javascript function when the dropdownlist change selection. I search the web [Dropdown using javascript onchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080098/dropdown-using-javascript-onchange) and modified my code but it still doesn't work.
Can someone tell me how to I call javascritp with clientID as parameter on dropdownlist change selection. Thanks in advance.

There is my code

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="dropL" runat="server"   onchange="setNote()"  >    </asp:dropdownlist>


function setNote() {
        alert ('ol');
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What is the issue? You don't show any code that demonstrates the problem.  Why do you need to pass a clientId?

Comment: please add item inside dropdown list and try again this is worked not an issue.

Comment: @Rick S, I used source databind on code behind to bind the data. The control is inside the gird, so I want to get the client id

Comment: If you want help you will need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first.

Comment: I found the problem. The code is no problem. On the project there is add attribution onchange event on code behind when datagrid itemDataBound. Therefore when I added on the aspx page, it doesn't worked. thanks for your time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="dropL" runat="server"   >    </asp:dropdownlist>



document.querySelector('#dropL').addEventListener("change", setNote);
function setNote() {
        alert ('ol');
 }
```